# Hiding viewable files in sharepoint

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, permissions, web-parts

Our company have some data in excels/images files that we want to make available to our employee through our sharepoint portal. However we do not want them to be able to download the files or copy/paste them to their PCs.

For this problem, I have written a silverlight app to display excel file and disable select/copy function. So now we upload the files to a document library, make this library 'viewable' to all users. We have a webpart that access the library and pass the links in encrypted form to the silverlight app to display. From the webpart page, the user can not see the links to the actually files. We will give the users link to this webpart page but not the document library itself.

However if a user goes to the 'All site contents' page, he can still easily see the document library and hence download the files.

My question is : is there a way to have the files viewable without letting the user having the link to download it ? 
If there are any better ways, I would like to know as well.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively simple way to hide the library from the "All site contents page" is by making it hidden. You can't do this from the UI, but you can either change the list instance (if you build the list definition and instance yourself) to have the list created as hidden, or you can open the list / library with SharePoint Designer and check "Hide from browsers" in the settings of the list.

Alternatively you can mark the list as hidden using the SharePoint Management Shell:

```
$w = get-spweb http://yoursite
$l = $w.Lists["yourlistname"]
$l.Hidden = $true
$l.Update()
```

Notice though that making a library hidden doesn't prevent users from browsing to it if they know the URL of the library. Through a developer proxy/network sniffer (like Fiddler), even if using Silverlight, one could figure out the url of the library if one really want to. Even if the links are passed to the Silverlight app encrypted, the Silverlight app itself will likely have to access the full urls, and as such they are trackable.